# Can I select from a destination table in a subquery?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Assume this is my Destination table:

```
    Name | Reason for Visit | Visit Number | Visit_date
    Dan  | Foo              | 1            | 04/03/2014
    Henry| Bar              | 1            | 05/07/2014
    Dan  | Tau              | 2            | 08/10/2014
```

I already have the Name, Reason_For_Visit and Visit_Date in my SOURCE table, and have to create the Visit_Number column. Am I allowed to sub-query the still-forming destination table like this and will I get the correct visit_number?

```
    insert into DESTINATION
    NAME,
    REASON_FOR_VISIT,
    (select count(d.Name)+1 from destination d where d.Name=Name) AS VISIT_NUMBER,
    VISIT_DATE
    from SOURCE
    ORDER BY VISIT_DATE ASC;
```

If rows are inserted one by one, I feel like I should get the correct Visit_number.

Comment: I dont know am i getiing you. You are saying that you want to create one column in the destintaion table or source table

Comment: Just switch the order of your from and where clauses in the subquery and you should be fine.

Comment: @JaazCole did as you said. Are you sure that the visit_number will be correct according to date?

Comment: Your syntax is all wrong.

Comment: Use SlimsGhosts answer.

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA I plan on using SlimsGhost's answer but could you let me know how the syntax is wrong? I'm pretty new to SQL and it would be helpful to know where I've gone wrong(except for performance issue mentioned below)

Comment: The above statement you gave needs to be in the following form:  INSERT INTO <> SELECT <> FROM <> WHERE <>.  Yours was not in this form.  ORDER BY is not needed since order is never guaranteed by the engine on SELECT * call.

Comment: Also, if you are adding data to the DESTINATION from the SOURCE.  A typical data warehousing issue, Slims answer will not work since it only looks at SOURCE data.  Not both sets.  Your answer, sub select will not work, since it will only be executed once.  The count my be increasing after each insert happen.  At that point, a TRIGGER would be best.  Match the [inserted] data set with the DESTINATION table, MAX(VISITNO) + ROWNUMBER() over the data set.  Good luck in your future TSQL endeavors!

Comment: Well that's what I wanted to know, about whether Count will increase dynamically as each insert operation is done! So the insert statement is not executed row by row, but executed once, getting the initial count and just using that for all inserted records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is YES - if you insert the first row, the second insert will see the first row already in the destination table.

Still, doing it row by row is an inefficient way to accomplish what you are doing. Why don't you try out something like this:

```
insert into destination
select 
    name, 
    reason_for_visit, 
    row_number() over (partition by name order by visit_date) as visit_number,
    visit_date
from source
```

The row_number() function will compute the visit_number correctly for you, and inserting all the rows with one query will definitely be more efficient.

Good luck!